# Spectroscopy on colored flames

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, visible-light, spectroscopy, wavelength, chemical-compounds

When observing colored fire through a spectrometer after adding substances like copper chloride or magnesium sulfate to change its color, what specific spectra are typically observed? How does the spectral composition of colored fire differ from that of regular fire?

Answer (score 2):

Normal fire has in general a continuous  spectrum if you add specific substances you get there special spectrum over the continuous . Usually you do not ad it to a strong fire , but just enough to get the spectra